# Combine multiple lines from one text file into one line

Tags: windows, string, batch-file

So I have a file with multiple lines of letters and numbers as shown:

```
a 
1
h
7
G
k
3
l
```

END

I need a type of code that combines them together and preferably outputs it into a variable as shown:

```
var=a1h7Gk2l
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "var="
for /f "usebackq" %%A in ("test.txt") do set var=!var!%%A
echo !var!
```

***Edit***
I assumed "END" does not physically exist in your file. If it does exist, then you can add the following line after the FOR statement to strip off the last 3 characters.

```
set "!var!=!var:~0,-3!"
```

Comment: I tried this and !var! ended up being the last character of the file, instead of all of the characters combined.

Comment: And yes, END isn't part of the file, someone edited it to make it seem like it is.

Comment: @Starletts: Must be me, I guess. It made the impression as if it was, so I included the word with other lines when reformatting them. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Starletts - Hmm, I can't imagine how it would not work for you. I've tested the code and it works fine. Are you sure you copied the code exactly, or else created an equivalent form?

Comment: I created an equivalent form containing no "setlocal" and replacing !'s with %'s because it wouldn't work otherwise. But of course, this doesn't work either. Perhaps you're using a different OS? I'm currently using Windows 7.

Comment: @Starletts - The delayed expansion using `!` requires the SETLOCAL. Have you tried the exact code I posted? I promise it works in XP, Vista and Win 7.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you just want to put the result into a file (as opposed to storing it in memory for some purpose), you could do something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
TYPE NUL >output.txt
FOR /F %%L IN (input.txt) DO (
  IF NOT "%%L" == "END" (<NUL >>output.txt SET /P "=%%L")
)
ECHO.>>output.txt
```

The last command may be unnecessary, depending on whether you need the End-of-Line symbol at, well, the end of the line.